# How to set "X11 DISPLAY variable was set"?

Tags: java, netbeans, x11, xming

I'm trying to remote into my raspberry with netbeans in Windows 10, but there is a report like this picture. I have received the following error, and I do not understand it. I see that some X11 DISPLAY variable needs to be set, but what value should I give it and how? I ever to trying with XMING but still same.

How can I fix this?

> Connecting to 192.168.137.75:22
> cmd : cd '/home/pi/NetBeansProjects//Gcrypt'; '/usr/bin/java'  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8   -jar /home/pi/NetBeansProjects//Gcrypt/dist/Gcrypt.jar
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
> java.awt.HeadlessException:
> No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
> at `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless`(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
> at `java.awt.Window.<init>`(Window.java:536)
> at `java.awt.Frame.<init>`(Frame.java:420)
> at `java.awt.Frame.<init>`(Frame.java:385)
> at `javax.swing.JFrame.<init>`(JFrame.java:189)
> at `gui.Main.<init>`(Main.java:21)
> at `gui.Main$4.run`(Main.java:162)
> at `java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch`(InvocationEvent.java:311)
> at `java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl`(EventQueue.java:756)
> at `java.awt.EventQueue.access$500`(EventQueue.java:97)
> at `java.awt.EventQueue$3.run`(EventQueue.java:709)
> at `java.awt.EventQueue$3.run`(EventQueue.java:703)
> at `java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged`(Native Method)
> at `java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege`(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
> at `java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent`(EventQueue.java:726)
> at `java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters`(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
> at `java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter`(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
> at `java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy`(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> at `java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents`(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at `java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents`(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
> at `java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run`(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Can you please provide the stack trace as text, not as a picture?

Comment: Please don't use images to include text. Images of text are not searchable, we can't copy from them to help you, and they aren't accessible. Please replace them with the text they contain, or augment them with the text they contain.

Comment: You must read, and report, your error messages accurately. You have it 100% wrong. The X11 DISPLAY variable was *not* set, and this is the problem. The only problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in the error message: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

first set the DISPLAY variable with this command, than run your program

```
export DISPLAY=yourRemoteHostHere:0.0
```